# How do you setup your domains to use same php.cgi but different PHP.ini

Tags: php, cgi, php.ini

I thought I had this figured out.

I built a php.cgi, but rather than have a copy of php.cgi in the /cgi-bin/ dir for each domain I have. I create a sym link to a common directory so they could all use the same php.cgi ref. Only problem is they are now also using the same PHP.INI file =/ I don't know how to fix this problem.

When I ran phpinfo on each domain, it referred to the first domain's PHP.INI file

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per domain, try to add this command to vhost config or root .htaccess file:

```
PHPIniDir <Path to folder containing php.ini file>
```

Edit: PHP doc indicates it's a Windows-only command but I used it on Redhat/Debian boxes without any problem.

Comment: Thanks Ill give it a try. If it works I'll mark your response here =]

Comment: Nope that didnt work. I got a server error.

Comment: Which error do you get in Apache logs?

Comment: Not sure where to set this becuz under the root there are many different domains being hosted.

Comment: This wont work.  Passing options in the vhost or using .htaccess required mod_php to be used. 

In order to use this you would need to have an instance of the binary for each user and set a relative path for the per user configuration at compile time.